# How to Create shortcut to FOLDER?

Tags: c#, .net, shortcut

i need some help.

I know how to create shortcut to a FILE, but how to do same with the folder?

Sorry for English, bros.

Comment: And what happens if you take the code to create a shortcut to a file, and change the file path to a folder path? And what class or method do you use to create a shortcut? What does its manpage say about folders? Or: what have you tried?

Comment: not clear. do you want to do this through any code?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but here is an example on how to create a shortcut in C#:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146757/Add-Remove-Startup-Folder-Shortcut-to-Your-App

**Note**: The link shows how to add a shortcut to the startup folder but you can easily change it to whatever and wherever you want.

If this is not enough, please explain (and add code) to what exactly you're trying to accomplish.